# How to protect my php files on the server from being requested

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm very new to php and web , now I'm learning about oop in php and how to divide my program into classes each in .php file. before now all I know about php program, that I may have these files into my root folder

1. home.php
2. about.php
3. products.php
4. contact.php

So, whenever the client requests any of that in the browser

```
http://www.example.com/home.php
http://www.example.com/about.php
http://www.example.com/products.php
http://www.example.com/contact.php
```

No problem, the files will output the proper page to the client.

Now, I have a problem. I also have files like these in the root folder

5. class1.php
6. class2.php
7. resources/myFunctions.php
8. resources/otherFunctions.php

how to prevent the user from requesting these files by typing something like this in the browser ?

```
 http://www.example.com/resources/myFunctions.php
```

The ways that I have been thinking of is by adding this line on top of every file of them `exit;`

Or, I know there is something called .htaccess that is an Apache configuration file that effect the way that the Apache works.

**What do real life applications do to solve this problem ?**

Comment: Just put them outside the public folders. Besides, if you put `exit;` on top, the script will stop, and it simply won't do anyhing.

Comment: Either way won't matter if they are only class definitions. Users would simply see a blank page. :)

Comment: @Qirel thanks. do you mean when I'm going to buy my first host, they will give me "Public" folders and "private" folders?

Comment: @georoot thanks. yes, but knowing that anyone can get a private file even without seeing anything on the screen makes me not comfortable. at least he will know the name of the files I have on the server :(

Comment: @Accountantم Yeah, anything outside the `public_html` folder can't be accessed directly.

Comment: @Accountantم first if you are calling each files by name, ex `index.php` or `auth.php` in itself is a bad design. Have a look at MVC architecture design. Also having the files outside webroot probably won't work(i can be wrong about this) because cgi does not allow include outside webroot

Comment: @georoot You can include from anywhere on the server, as long as the access isn't restricted. E.g. you can include`/home/user/functions/somefile.php` (outside the public folders) from the public files.

Comment: @Qirel even if that is the case, i am not sure that the structure is in the best practices. Think of nightmare on deployment part :D , Just an opinion i would never do it

Comment: Personally, I place every file that isn't displaying content (typical classes, functions, et cetera) outside the public folder. There's no need for them to be public, really - they can be included from anywhere on the server, as long as the access (permissions and the likes) isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would indeed use whatever server side configuration options are available to you.

Depending on how your hosting is set up you could either modify the include path for PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) or restricting the various documents/directories to specific hosts/subnets/no access in the Apache site configuration (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).

If you are on shared hosting, this level of lock down isn't usually possible, so you are stuck with using the Apache rewrite rules using a combination of a easy to handle file naming convention (ie, classFoo.inc.php and classBar.inc.php), the .htaccess file and using the FilesMatch directive to block access to *.inc.php - http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess/

FWIW all else being equal the Apache foundation says it is better/more efficient to do it in server side config vs. using .htaccess IF that option is available to you.

Answer (score 1):

A real-life application often uses a so-called `public/` or `webroot/` folder in the root of the project where all files to be requested over the web reside in.

This `.htaccess` file then forwards all HTTP requests to this folder with internal URL rewrites like the following:

```
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/  [L] # match either nothing (www.mydomain.com)
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ webroot/$1 [L] # or anything else (www.mydomain.com/home.php)
```

.htaccess uses regular expressions to match the request URI (everything in the URL after the hostname) and prepends that with `webroot/`, in this example.

`www.mydomain.com/home.php` becomes `www.mydomain.com/webroot/home.php`,
`www.mydomain.com/folder/file.php` becomes `www.mydomain.com/webroot/folder/file.php`

Note: this will not be visible in the url in the browser.

When configured properly, all files that are placed outside of this folder can not be accessed by a regular HTTP request. Your application however (your php scripts), can still access those private files, because PHP runs on your server, so it has filesystem access to those files.